# How do I show a local video file with object and embed tags?

Tags: html, video, embed, object-tag

So my video file is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Videos\Test\intro.wmv. I just want to run the video locally on my web page.

It has to run on IE8/WinXP. So no HTML5.

This is what I have so far:

```
<object width="100%" height="100%"
type="video/x-ms-asf" url="http://localhost/Videos/Test/intro.wmv" data="intro.wmv"
classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
<param name="url" value="http://localhost/Videos/Test/intro.wmv">
<param name="filename" value="intro.wmv">
<param name="autostart" value="1">
<param name="uiMode" value="full" />
<param name="autosize" value="1">
<param name="playcount" value="1">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="http://localhost/Videos/Test/intro.wmv" width="100%" height="100%" autostart="true" showcontrols="true" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: the WMP shows but nothing plays.

Comment: What happens if you open the video url directly in browser? Does it show you "save as" dialog, opens WMP or shows an error page? Also try right clicking on the player and see if it shows an error/error code (it should). Post it in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Try something more simple to begin like :

```
<object data="./Videos/Test/intro.wmv" type="video/x-ms-wmv"  width="100%" height="100%">
  <param name="src" value="./Videos/Test/intro.wmv">
  <param name="autoStart" value="1">
  alt : <a href="./Videos/Test/intro.wmv">My video name</a>
</object>
```

OR HTML5

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">  
    <source src="./Videos/Test/intro.wmv" type="video//x-ms-wmv" />   
    <!-- <track src="subtitles_en.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English"> -->     
    Nav doesn't support html5 video
</video>
```

Comment: any of those ? What happened ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
<object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
  <embed src="movie.swf" width="320" height="240" />
</object> 
</video>
```

Save this as html file in the same folder, where the video is, this is in html 5, its always good to give relative path then the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

This works at least.

```
<object width="100%" height="100%"
type="video/x-ms-asf" url="/wiki/Videos/Test/intro.wmv" data="/wiki/Videos/Test/intro.wmv"
classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
<param name="url" value="/wiki/Videos/Test/intro.wmv">
<param name="filename" value="/wiki/Videos/Test/intro.wmv">
<param name="autostart" value="1">
<param name="uiMode" value="full" />
<param name="autosize" value="1">
<param name="playcount" value="1">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="/wiki/Videos/Test/intro.wmv" width="100%" height="100%" autostart="true" showcontrols="true" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed>
</object>
```